# IDQ mapping output variables in workflow

Tags: informatica

Issue:

How do you include you mapping output variables in the workflow without having to use a human task?

Basically I have one row of data that I want to push out and to be included in e.g. the body of the Notification task or as an attachment.

FYI - we are not using power center, only the developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved a similar situation using a flat file output from the Mapping and Command Tasks in the workflow.  Here is a link to where I explained the process in the Informatica Data Quality Community forum:  https://communities.informatica.com/thread/15717

Comment: please include all relevant info from your prior explanation in the post. SO does not like link-only answers.